# Looking at a Kohen's hands on Video

Tags: technology, see-sight-vision-blind, birchas-kohanim, recording

One is not allowed to look at a Kohen's hands while he is performing Birchas Kohanim (source: my Artscroll siddur, but it is well-known too)

Would this also apply if one was looking at a video of the Cohen? (or a picture?)

Answer (score 5):

The prohibition seems to refer only to the time that *birkas kohanim* is actually taking place (*Shulchan Aruch - Orach Chayim* [128:23](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%9B%D7%97_%D7%9B%D7%92)) and to serve the purpose of allowing the onlookers to maintain focus on being the object of blessing by standing at attention and looking down. Though one should always C[O](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33731/can-one-replace-an-antecedent)LOR, this would imply that watching a video would not detract from the purpose of averting one's eyes and therefore be permissible.